# Heroku env variables working in node js but not React

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku, deployment, production-environment

I have a full stack app with Node as backend and React as front end.
I have config files for both Node and react and I have variables stored in heroku for access keys. My backend is getting those keys but Front end is giving invalid keys error.

Is there another way of using env variables in react ?

I am using it like this in both Node and React :

```
apiKey: process.env.API_KEY
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. In React, only the variables that start with REACT_APP_ are embedded in our app.

So the variable should be named REACT_APP_API_KEY to be used